# SQL : 4 conditions combined with OR

Tags: sql, postgresql

The question is,

Determine names of all the ships in Ships table that meet a combination of at least four criteria from the following list: numGuns = 8 bore = 15 displacement = 32000 type = bb launched = 1915 class = Kongo country = USA.

I found the answer for this exercise.

The answer is,

```
SELECT s.name from ship s,classes c 
WHERE s.class=c.class AND 
    ((numGuns = 8 AND bore = 15 AND displacement = 32000 AND type = 'bb') 
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND bore = 15 AND displacement = 32000 AND launched = 1915) 
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND bore = 15 AND displacement = 32000 AND c.class = 'Kongo') 
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND bore = 15 AND displacement = 32000 AND country = 'USA') 
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND bore = 15 AND type = 'bb' AND launched = 1915) 
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND bore = 15 AND type = 'bb' AND c.class = 'kongo')  
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND bore = 15 AND type = 'bb' AND country = 'USA')  
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND bore = 15 AND launched = 1915 AND c.class = 'Kongo')  
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND bore = 15 AND launched = 1915 AND country = 'USA')  
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND bore = 15 AND c.class = 'Kongo' AND country = 'USA')  
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND displacement = 32000 AND type = 'bb' AND launched = 1915)  
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND displacement = 32000 AND type = 'bb' AND c.class = 'kongo')  
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND displacement = 32000 AND type = 'bb' AND country = 'USA')  
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND displacement = 32000 AND launched = 1915 AND c.class = 'Kongo')  
        OR (numGuns = 8 AND displacement = 32000 AND launched = 1915 AND country = 'USA') O
```

My question is,

Is there any other simple way check the conditions.

Comment: Please give meaningful title.

Comment: Yes, just move around your `WHERE` clauses to simplify them.

Comment: @Ruslan Which means ?

Comment: Why not put all those clauses into another table and then find the intersection between the two tables?

Comment: Hi @suresh , I second Ed Heal. There are too many conditions in your sql query. In an exercise , it may work but if you put that query into a work envirionment, your query has a sure chance to get rejected ...

Comment: numGuns is 8 in every test so you can extract numGuns=8 and ... or

Comment: so it means 2 are false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast from `boolean` to `integer` yields 0 or 1:

```
select s.name
from
    ship s
    inner join
    classes c using (class)
where
    (numguns = 8)::int +
    (bore = 15)::int +
    (displacement = 32000)::int +
    (type = 'bb')::int + 
    (launched = 1915)::int + 
    (class = 'Kongo')::int +
    (country = 'USA')::int
    >= 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE WHEN` statements to count the number of matching columns for each record, and then wrap this query to get only records with 4 or more matching columns.

```
SELECT t.name
FROM
(
    SELECT s.name,
        CASE WHEN s.numGuns = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c1,
        CASE WHEN s.dbore = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c2,
        CASE WHEN s.displacement = 32000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c3,
        CASE WHEN s.type = 'bb' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c4,
        CASE WHEN s.launched = 1915 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c5,
        CASE WHEN c.class = 'Kongo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c6,
        CASE WHEN s.country = 'USA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c7
    FROM ship s INNER JOIN classes c ON s.class = c.class
) t
WHERE (t.c1 + t.c2 + t.c3 + t.c4 + t.c5 + t.c6 + t.c7) >= 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly from a predicate standpoint, yes, for example the last 5 predicates:

```
OR (numGuns = 8 AND displacement = 32000 AND type = 'bb' AND launched = 1915)  
OR (numGuns = 8 AND displacement = 32000 AND type = 'bb' AND c.class = 'kongo')  
OR (numGuns = 8 AND displacement = 32000 AND type = 'bb' AND country = 'USA')  
OR (numGuns = 8 AND displacement = 32000 AND launched = 1915 AND c.class = 'Kongo')  
OR (numGuns = 8 AND displacement = 32000 AND launched = 1915 AND country = 'USA')
```

can be:

```
OR ((numGuns = 8 AND displacement = 32000) AND 
    ((type = 'bb' AND launched = 1915) OR 
    (type = 'bb' AND c.class = 'kongo') OR 
    (type = 'bb' AND country = 'USA') OR 
    (launched = 1915 AND c.class = 'Kongo') OR 
    (launched = 1915 AND country = 'USA')))
```